# Regex Help - Search and replace

Tags: regex

Following is the combination of words that I need to search and replace:

```
[Cc]ontestants:
[Cc]ontestants :
[Cc]ontestant:
[Cc]ontestant :
```

Is following correct?

```
'/[Cc]ontestant(:| :|s:|s :)/'
```

The sentence (or line) will start with the word and end with : (with or without a blank space before :) followed by some other words in the sentence, or no words after :.

Just need to match and replace the above combination with a new word - say MyWord.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/ for testing regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
[Cc]ontestants?\s?\:
```

Broken down:

- `[Cc]` -> Match on 'C' or 'c'
- `ontestant` -> Match on 'ontestant' literal
- `s?` -> Match on an optional 's' literal
- `\s?` -> Match on optional whitespace
- `\:` -> Match on a literal ':'

See https://regex101.com/r/gA6xS5/1 for example.

Answer (score 2):

You may reduce it to,

```
[Cc]ontestants?\s*:
```

or

```
[Cc]ontestants?\h*:
```

> The sentence (or line) will start with the word and end with :

If it's at the start then use start of the line anchor `^`

```
^[Cc]ontestants?\h*:
```

Comment: Sentence or line will be one of the three cases below:

Ends with : and then a new lline.

Or

: rusticnomand somone-else blah blah

Or

:rusticnomand somone-else blah blah

Answer (score 1):

If the line starts and end as described I suggest the following:

```
^\[Cc\]ontestants?\s?\:$
```

The "$" at the end ensures that there are no further characters after the ":". I.e. `[Cc]ontestant:d` wouldn't match.